# How do I break out of the async cycle?

Tags: dart

In Dart, you can tell the VM to wait for a `Future` by calling `await`.

The thing is that you can only call `await` in an async function, which returns a ... `Future`.

So if I have a function which doesn't take a long time to run, and has to be run in a function who's type is *not* async, how do I break out of the async chain?

Comment: And I suspect it's possible since there are dart functions which obviously use futures inside (such as file manipulation) but show a futureless public api.

Comment: The `File` API has synchronous (blocking) operations as well as asynchronous ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as breaking out of the async cycle. It's possible to have sync functions to call async code, but the result of the async code won't be available yet when the sync function returns.

Comment: So how are there libraries which open files (or call Java code), which requires async, which don't return futures?

Comment: I would need to see a concrete example. You can do async code without futures, but that dosn't really change anything.

Comment: Somehow [FutureBuilder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) gets a value out of a future in an (ultimately) non-async build function

Comment: The `FutureBuilder` receives the `Future` and waits for it to complete (that is after `build` completed) and when the `Future` eventually completes, `FutureBuilder` calls `setState` to have the tree rebuilt.

Comment: Is that the recommended approach to doing things through Futures (set state when future finishes)?

Comment: It's an easy way. There is also `StreamBuilder` for multiple events. But "doing things" is quite generic. It's also common to execute multiple async calls where one waits for another using `await` and only the final one with the final result is passed to `FutureBuilder` to cause a screen update when it completes.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between a synchronous function and an asynchronous function is that the former is done when it returns, and the latter is still working in the background when it returns, which is why it returns a `Future` which will complete when it's *really* done.
That is the distinction - an asynchronous function is one that returns a `Future`. The `async` marker is not what makes the function asynchronous, it's just *one* way of implementing an asynchronous function. You can also have functions without the `async` marker which return a `Future`.

You can call an asynchronous function from a synchronous function. However, there is no way for the synchronous function to delay its return, so it must return before the future completes. It can set up a listener on the future, `future.then((value) { doSomethingWith(value); })`, but that listener will certainly only be called after the synchronous function has returned. That `then`-call also returns a future, so the synchronous function has to ignore some `Future`. That's fine. You are allowed to ignore a future when you don't need the result.

Whatever you do, you can't get the *result* of a `Future` in a synchronous function before it returns.